# Deleting a listview Item through Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I'm attempting to make an alert dialog remove an item in a ListView but I can't find a solution to how I do it.
Here is my code:

```
contactsListView.setLongClickable(true);
    contactsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactsActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Contact Removal");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove this contact?");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, I'm sure!", new HandleAlertDialogListener());
            builder.setNegativeButton("No, I've changed my mind", new HandleAlertDialogListener());
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here is my HandleAlertDialogListener()

```
private class HandleAlertDialogListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
}
```

the problem is that I can't refer to the position of the item I want removed.
Another question is what are the which values for the dialog's buttons? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: position attribute in onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) is the position inside the ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onItemLongClick() make your **position** parameter final ,  then create your alert dialog like this :

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Delete").setMessage("Review").setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
          // use position here.
        }
      }).setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_reask, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
          dialog.dismiss();
        }
      }).create().show();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have an Adapter to show items in a ListView?

If so, you should delete an item like I said:

```
myDataList.remove(position);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Where position is an attribute in this method:

```
onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```